# Change tungsten install directory in continuent-tools-hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive

Hi im using this to load data in to hive from hadoop.

https://github.com/continuent/continuent-tools-hadoop

This gives the following error:

```
ls: cannot access /opt/continuent/tungsten/tungsten-replicator/: No such file or directory
```

It is obvious as i installed in my tungsten in different folder not the default one.

Where I can change the URL of the tungsten directory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

execute ./bin/load-reduce-check with -r /mnt1/continuent

Comment: Be aware though, that when you are updating your "continuent-tools-hadoop", this change will be overwritten.

Comment: Is it possible to pass this as a config from outside?

Comment: For my knowledge i dont think so

Comment: Sorry for early comment it can be sent form outside with -r